# Valor de coluna duplicado, como evitar?

Tags: mysql, sql

Como faço exatamente para que essa coluna **valorAuxilio** não tenha seus valores duplicados, ou seja, em vez de quatro linhas de resultado seriam apenas duas.

```
SELECT p.nome,
       d.nome,
       c.valorAuxilio
FROM sca_pessoa p

INNER JOIN sca_dependente d ON p.idPessoa = d.idPessoa
INNER JOIN sispro_contrato c ON p.idPessoa = c.idPessoa

WHERE p.nome LIKE '%ADEMAR MAGA%'
AND c.idSituacaoContrato = 3 ORDER BY c.valorAuxilio;
```

[image: Valores Duplicados]

Comment: Tentou um `group by` ?

Comment: Você poderia ter colocado o código sem ser uma imagem... isso dificulta enormemente para a pessoa que quer dar uma resposta. =\

Comment: Desculpa Miguel, é pq quis botar o resultado junto, pensando que iria melhorar visualização na próxima me corrijo sobre isso.

Comment: A visualização é importante, assim como o código. Agora ficou perfeito! =D

Comment: Os dados estão duplicados em uma das tabelas. Por quê?

Comment: @bfavaretto ai vc me pegou. kkk Eu não sei bem se posso dizer se são valores duplicados é como se fossem contratos diferentes, mas valores que é igual. #SouEstagiario

Comment: O que eu entendo é que o Ademar tem dois contratos com dois dependentes em cada. Para trazer uma linha por contrato, é preciso juntar os nomes desses dependentes numa única linha, como na resposta do Miguel Angelo. Ou seja: não é uma duplicação como eu achava inicialmente.

Comment: @bfavaretto entendi o que você diz, mas devido a falta de conhecimento acho que não sei como explicar. Mas essa tabela de _contratos é como uma "ligadora" de outras tabelas e esse **valorAuxilio** também existe na tabela com mesmo valor chamada **relatorioIndividualDependente**.

Comment: Teste a query do Miguel Angelo e você vai entender como funciona. Ela agrupa dados do mesmo contrato numa única linha. Como cada contrato tem 2 dependentes, eles aparecerão numa coluna só, separados por `;` como especificado no `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: A ordem dos `INNER JOIN`s me provoca uma sensação estranha.

Comment: Aliás, leiam os comments da outra questão, e vejam os edits. Acho que compensa continuar lá. Isso tem acontecido muito aqui de duplicatas mutantes, depois acho que é caso para discutir no meta.

Comment: Minha cabeça acostumada com orientação a objetos esperaria essa ordem: sca_pessoa -> sispro_contrato -> sca_dependente

Comment: @phpricardo se continuarmos a discussão na original, as pessoas já vão ter acesso a tudo que já foi tentado, e vai ajudar a todos entenderem o problema. Dividir a questão só atrapalha a todos. Lembre que você pode a qualquer momento acrescentar naquela mais detalhes, aumentando a pergunta com os detalhes que precisar.

Comment: Por mim tudo bem, só achava que as ideias eram diferentes, por isso abrir um novo.

Comment: @phpricardo sem problemas, não é uma reclamação, e marcar como duplicata não é nenhum tipo de reprovação nem punição. A idéia é ajudar, mas se continuar aqui, você vai ter que explicar tudo de novo pra quem for ajudar.

Answer (score 3):

Você teria de agrupar em cima do campo `valorAuxilio` e usar funções de agregação em cima das outras colunas.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.nome SEPARATOR ';'),
       GROUP_CONCAT(d.nome SEPARATOR ';'),
       c.valorAuxilio
FROM sca_pessoa p

INNER JOIN sca_dependente d ON p.idPessoa = d.idPessoa
INNER JOIN sispro_contrato c ON p.idPessoa = c.idPessoa

WHERE p.nome LIKE '%ADEMAR MAGA%'
AND c.idSituacaoContrato = 3 ORDER BY c.valorAuxilio;

GROUP BY c.valorAuxilio;
```

**Referência:**

[GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Eu não entendi esse teu código.

Comment: Estou agrupando os resultados usando a coluna `valorAuxilio` como pivot, de forma que não existam duplicatas no resultado desta coluna... mas para isso, tenho que agregar as outras colunas, pois cada uma delas possui dois valores para cada valor de `valorAuxilio`... escolhi a função de agregação `GROUP_CONCAT` para isso, para concatenar os resultados dessas colunas, pois são strings.

Comment: O que está me encafifando é, por que existe a necessidade de agrupar? Se fossem `LEFT JOIN`s eu entenderia, mas os `INNER` indicam dados duplicados em alguma tabela. **EDIT** Acho que agora entendi, vou comentar acima.

Comment: Essa discussão ja está até mais longa aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12273/valor-de-coluna-duplicado-como-evitar

Comment: Levei um negativo sem explicação!!! =D

Answer (score 0):

Cara tenta usar o LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT p.nome,
       d.nome,
       c.valorAuxilio
FROM sca_pessoa p

LEFT JOIN sca_dependente d ON p.idPessoa = d.idPessoa
LEFT JOIN sispro_contrato c ON p.idPessoa = c.idPessoa

WHERE p.nome LIKE '%ADEMAR MAGA%'
AND c.idSituacaoContrato = 3 ORDER BY c.valorAuxilio;
```

Posta a description das tabelas ai para a gente dar uma olhada.